# Android Room Database - "Couldn't read row" error throws from the room generated code

Tags: android, sql, database, android-room

I have developed a music player Android app that stores song metadata using Room Database. The `AudioMetadataEntity` table represents the song metadata, and I'm encountering an issue when querying the database.

```
@Entity(tableName = AudioMetadataEntity.TABLE_NAME)
data class AudioMetadataEntity(
   @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false) @ColumnInfo(name = ID) val id: Long,
   @ColumnInfo(name = TITLE) val title: String = "",
   @ColumnInfo(name = TRACK) val track: Int = 0,
   @ColumnInfo(name = YEAR) val year: Int = 0,
   @ColumnInfo(name = DURATION) val duration: Long = 0,
   @ColumnInfo(name = DATA) val data: String = "",
   @ColumnInfo(name = DATE_ADDED) val dateAdded: Long = currentTimeSeconds(),
   @ColumnInfo(name = DATE_MODIFIED) val dateModified: Long = currentTimeSeconds(),
   @ColumnInfo(name = ALBUM_ID) val albumId: Long = 0,
   @ColumnInfo(name = ALBUM_NAME) val albumName: String = "",
   @ColumnInfo(name = ARTIST_ID) val artistId: Long = 0,
   @ColumnInfo(name = ARTIST_NAME) val artistName: String = "",
   @ColumnInfo(name = ALBUM_ARTIST) val albumArtist: String = "",
   @ColumnInfo(name = COMPOSER) val composer: String = "",
   @ColumnInfo(name = SIZE) val size: Long = 0,
   @ColumnInfo(name = GENRE) val genre: String = "",
   @ColumnInfo(name = IS_AUDIOBOOK) val isAudiobook: Boolean = false,
   @ColumnInfo(name = IS_BLACKLISTED) val isBlacklisted: Boolean = false,
) {
   companion object {
       const val TABLE_NAME = "audio_metadata"
       const val ID = "_id"
       const val TITLE = "title"
       const val TRACK = "track"
       const val YEAR = "year"
       const val ARTIST_ID = "artist_id"
       const val ARTIST_NAME = "artist_name"
       const val ALBUM_ID = "album_id"
       const val ALBUM_NAME = "album_name"
       const val ALBUM_ARTIST = "album_artist"
       const val COMPOSER = "composer"
       const val SIZE = "size"
       const val DATE_ADDED = "date_added"
       const val DATE_MODIFIED = "date_modified"
       const val GENRE = "genre"
       const val DURATION = "duration"
       const val DATA = "data"
       const val IS_BLACKLISTED = "is_blacklisted"
       const val IS_AUDIOBOOK = "is_audiobook"
   }
}
```

In the DAO class, I have a method called `getSongSearch`, which retrieves songs based on a search query. The method internally calls the `getSongs` method with a custom SQLite query.

```
private fun getSongSearch(
query: String,
orderBy: String = "",
includeBlacklisted: Boolean = false,
filterShortDuration: Int = AudioPrefUtil.filterTrackDuration,
): List<AudioMetadataEntity> = getSongs(buildSearchQuery(query, orderBy, includeBlacklisted, filterShortDuration))


@RawQuery(observedEntities = [AudioMetadataEntity::class])
abstract fun getSongs(query: SupportSQLiteQuery): List<AudioMetadataEntity>



fun buildSearchQuery(
query: String = "",
orderBy: String = DefaultSortOption.songs.getSQLOrderBy(),
includeBlacklisted: Boolean = false,
filterShortDuration: Int = AudioPrefUtil.filterTrackDuration,
): SupportSQLiteQuery = SimpleSQLiteQuery(
buildString {
append("$FROM_AUDIO_METADATA WHERE ${AudioMetadataEntity.TITLE} LIKE ?")
if (!includeBlacklisted) append(" AND ${${AudioMetadataEntity.IS_BLACKLISTED} = 0}")
append(" AND ${AudioMetadataEntity.DURATION} >= $filterShortDuration")
append(" AND ${${AudioMetadataEntity.IS_AUDIOBOOK} = 0}")
if (orderBy.isNotEmpty()) append(" ORDER BY $orderBy")
}, arrayOf("%$query%")
)
```

When I call `getSongSearch(query = "")`, it should return all the metadata. The method works fine on most devices, but some users are reporting crashes with the following error:

The error seems to be related to reading row 1409's ID from the CursorWindow. The app reads over 1000 songs before encountering this issue.

What could be causing this error, and how can I fix it to ensure smooth retrieval of all songs' metadata?

```
Exception java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 1409, col 0 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
  at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetLong
  at android.database.CursorWindow.getLong (CursorWindow.java:536)
  at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getLong (AbstractWindowedCursor.java:78)
  at com.shaiban.audioplayer.mplayer.audio.common.metadata.AudioMetadataDao_Impl.__entityCursorConverter_comShaibanAudioplayerMplayerAudioCommonMetadataAudioMetadataEntity (AudioMetadataDao_Impl.java)
  at com.shaiban.audioplayer.mplayer.audio.common.metadata.AudioMetadataDao_Impl.getSongs (AudioMetadataDao_Impl.java)
  at com.shaiban.audioplayer.mplayer.audio.common.metadata.AudioMetadataDao.getSongSearch (AudioMetadataDao.java)
  at com.shaiban.audioplayer.mplayer.audio.common.metadata.AudioMetadataDao.getSongSearch$default (AudioMetadataDao.java)
  at com.shaiban.audioplayer.mplayer.audio.common.metadata.AudioMetadataDao.getSongs (AudioMetadataDao.java)
  at com.shaiban.audioplayer.mplayer.audio.common.helpers.metadata.MetadataUpdateHelper$Companion.deleteObsoleteSongs (MetadataUpdateHelper.java)
  at com.shaiban.audioplayer.mplayer.audio.common.helpers.metadata.MetadataUpdateHelper$Companion.syncMediaStore (MetadataUpdateHelper.java)
  at com.shaiban.audioplayer.mplayer.audio.song.SongDatastore.syncMediaStore (SongDatastore.java)
  at com.shaiban.audioplayer.mplayer.audio.song.SongRepository.syncMediaStore (SongRepository.java)
  at com.shaiban.audioplayer.mplayer.audio.common.repository.AudioRepository.syncMediaStore (AudioRepository.java)
  at com.shaiban.audioplayer.mplayer.audio.service.MusicService$handleChangeInternal$1.invokeSuspend (MusicService.java)
  at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith (BaseContinuationImpl.java)
  at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run (DispatchedTask.java)
  at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.LimitedDispatcher.run (LimitedDispatcher.java)
  at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.TaskImpl.run (TaskImpl.java)
  at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely (CoroutineScheduler.java)
  at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask (CoroutineScheduler.java)
  at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker (CoroutineScheduler.java)
  at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run (CoroutineScheduler.java)
```

I've tried from different devices, different song counts, queries. but so far unable to reproduce the issue.

I've gone throught stackoverflow questions and android documentation for Room. I'm not sure what i'm missing but I haven't gotten any solution.

Edit 1:

Getting similar crashes as well. seems like issue happens after reading long no. of rows but not sure.

```
Exception java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 1381, col 0 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
  at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetLong
  at android.database.CursorWindow.getLong (CursorWindow.java:539)
  at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getLong (AbstractWindowedCursor.java:78)
  at com.shaiban.audioplayer.mplayer.audio.common.metadata.AudioMetadataDao_Impl.__entityCursorConverter_comShaibanAudioplayerMplayerAudioCommonMetadataAudioMetadataEntity (AudioMetadataDao_Impl.java)
  at com.shaiban.audioplayer.mplayer.audio.common.metadata.AudioMetadataDao_Impl.access$100 (AudioMetadataDao_Impl.java)
  at com.shaiban.audioplayer.mplayer.audio.common.metadata.AudioMetadataDao_Impl$4.call (AudioMetadataDao_Impl.java)
  at com.shaiban.audioplayer.mplayer.audio.common.metadata.AudioMetadataDao_Impl$4.call (AudioMetadataDao_Impl.java)
  at androidx.room.CoroutinesRoom$Companion$createFlow$1$1$1.invokeSuspend (CoroutinesRoom.java)
  at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith (BaseContinuationImpl.java)
  at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run (DispatchedTask.java)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1137)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:1012)
```